Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception
Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
在使用spring-cloud-gateway和nacos中遇到的ConcurrentModification异常分析

how to solve it?
reload the service, but can not solve it.
maybe attack cause?

Please, give more detailed information about the problem. Provide a reproducible example  and detail the error you are experiencing.
